# Streaming video between processes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, kinect

This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23530705/increasing-wcf-duplex-callback-maxsize) which I asked earlier.

I am trying to use a [WCF Duplex service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to control (start, stop, enable feature) a number of Kinect devices. Beyond this, I would also like to stream the video feed I receive  from a Windows Service to a client WPF app. I am doing this because I need the properties of a Windows Service such as automatic startup for the application.

Having tried to use Duplex service callbacks to stream the data and run into some issues as described in the other question. I'm starting to wonder if a [Memory-Mapped File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) is a better approach.

The device will roughly 30 times a second issue the following call.

```
private byte[] _ColorPixels;

private void Sensor_AllFramesReady(object sender, Microsoft.Kinect.AllFramesReadyEventArgs e)
{
    using (ColorImageFrame frame = e.OpenColorImageFrame())
    {
        frame.CopyPixelDataTo(_ColorPixels);
        //_ColorPixels will now have a large array which is the video stream
    }
}
```

at which point I have an array that contains at least 1,228,800 elements. I'd now like to forward this data to another process.

So what is the best way to stream live video data between processes in C#?

Answer (score 0):

It's not trivial to stream video as it takes a lot of bandwidth, you need to have a cache to prevent stuttering when the bandwidth is throttled.

Use a streaming library like http://www.streamcoders.com/.